# ¿Cómo puedo saber la duración de una canción mp3 en Java usando la librería Javazoom?

Tags: java, javazoom

Estoy haciendo un reproductor de música en java, pero no sé que hacer para sacar el tiempo de duración de la canción. Estoy usando Javazoom.

Comment: Hola Ismar, te recomiendo que empieces leyendo la guía ["Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta"](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y que edites tu pregunta siguiendo esta otra guía [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede usar algo asi, ajustar el retorno para obtener la duraccion en la unidad deseada:

```
private int algunMetodo(File file) {

    AudioFileFormat audioFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
    Map<String, Object>  properties = ((TAudioFileFormat) audioFileFormat).properties();


    Long micro = (Long) properties.get("duration");
    int a      = (int) (micro / 1000);
    int r      = (a / 1000) % 60;

    return r;
}
```

http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/documents.html

Al final del link puede ver `Where is the list of all available properties ?` donde se encuentran los parametros standard, y es "duration" uno de ellos que empleamos asi: `properties.get("duration");` para buscar dentro del `Map` y la documentacion nos dice que devuelve un `[Long]` de ahi el cast.